# How pass an array and its dimension from Python to Fortran and use it among subroutines?

Tags: python, arrays, fortran, f2py

So what I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. Define an array in Python;
2. Pass that array **and its dimension** into Fortran via `f2py`;
3. Use that array among various subroutines within the Fortran code. (The Fortran code does not change the array.)

I already know that this is impossible in a common block from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15964961/6037395).
The Fortran code consists of many separate scripts, so I cannot use `contains` either.
Is it possible that this can be achieved otherwise?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

yes it's possible. Here is one way of doing it.

Create fortran code like so...

```
!example.f90
subroutine compute(x_1d, x_2d, nx, ny)

  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307) !double precision

  ! input variables
  integer, intent(in)       :: nx
  integer, intent(in)       :: ny
  real(kind=dp), intent(in) :: x_1d(nx), x_2d(nx, ny)

  !f2py intent(in) x_1d, x_2d

  print *, 'Inside fortran code'
  print *, 'shape(x_1d) = ',  shape(x_1d)
  print *, 'shape(x_2d) = ',  shape(x_2d)

end subroutine compute
```

Compile it with f2py to make a module you can import into python.

```
python -m numpy.f2py -m example -h example.pyf example.f90
python -m numpy.f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 example.pyf example.f90
```

Now you should have a shared object file called something like `example.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` which can be imported directly into python like so:

```py
#example.py
from example import compute
import numpy as np

def main():

    nx = 2
    ny = 4

    x = np.random.rand(nx)
    y = np.random.rand(nx, ny)

    print(compute.__doc__)

    compute(x, y)

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running `python example.py` gives:

```
compute(x_1d,x_2d,[nx,ny])

Wrapper for ``compute``.

Parameters
----------
x_1d : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (nx)
x_2d : input rank-2 array('d') with bounds (nx,ny)

Other Parameters
----------------
nx : input int, optional
    Default: shape(x_1d, 0)
ny : input int, optional
    Default: shape(x_2d, 1)

 Inside fortran code
 shape(x_1d) =            2
 shape(x_2d) =            2           4
```

Notice you don't need to explicitly pass the dimensions. It is handled automagically by `f2py` and the directives we put in the fortran code `!f2py`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I am busy with other work to do recently. I will try to implement your solution as soon as I have time!